# How to reference variable value in index

Tags: python, json, indexing, ansible, jinja2

When i hardcode the value it works fine.For Example-

```
- name: display number
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_facts.partition[2] }}"
```

OUPUT

```
ok: [host] => {
    "msg": "786"
}
```

But when i dynamically find the value of the variable and reference that value, it doesn't work.

```
- name: display number
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_facts.partition[number] }}"

## Where: number = 2, finding this value dynamically and setting as fact
```

OUPUT

```
 The error was: 'list object' has no attribute u'2'
```

i also tried converting the number variable into integer using

```
set_fact:
   number: "{{ number | int }}"
```

But no Luck. Any one can help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Post `msg: "{{ ansible_facts.partition }}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as below:

```
- name: display number
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_facts.partition[number|int] }}"
```